# How to disable "X-Powered-By" response header in create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, create-react-app

I'm working on a react.js app using `Create-react-app`, in the response headers I'm seeing an Express's `x-powered-by` header and I want to disable this particular header field. Are there ways to achieve this? In the `Next.js` we can disable this header field by adding some code to config file, can we achieve the same in my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is a client side framework and doesn't handle serving your application to a browser. Whatever system you are using to host your application is responsible for that header. Some of the CRA templates use `webpack-dev-server` for `npm start` which is built on Express and is probably what's showing the header. As this isn't actually part of your app, there isn't much point to turning it off even if you can.

Comment: hey Sam, just now I saw your twitter page and I came know that you're a Robotics Engineer. I've deep interest in Robots, but unfortunately I'm only a software engineer.. could you please help me learn more about robotics, maybe could you suggest a book/course, that would really help. Thanks a ton. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a look at [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet), this will remove the x-powered-by header as well as enhancing security by setting other http headers (see docs. for details)

```
const express = require("express");
const helmet = require("helmet");

const app = express();

app.use(helmet());

app.get("/test", (req, resp) => { 
    resp.send('Testing with Helmet');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

You'll see when you use helmet that the `X-Powered-By: Express` header is no longer present.

If you *just* want to hide the `x-powered-by` header, I'd suggest trying:

```
const express = require("express");
const helmet = require("helmet");

const app = express();

app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());

app.get("/test", (req, resp) => { 
    resp.send('Testing with Helmet');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: server/api is being written in different language & web framework.. i dont have access to express app in `create-react-app` :(

Comment: The headers come from the server, so I don't think it will be possible to remove them without having access to it. You could wrap the api calls to filter headers, but I don't know what purpose this would serve...